# changing the name of image file PHP or Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form which has a textbox and a file select button. What I would like to do is:

1. User enters a name in the textbox
2. User selects an image file from thier local directory
3. Rename the selected image file name to the name entered in the text box.

I have look at a number of ways to do this using server side (PHP) and Client side using Jquery.

Which is the best approach and can anyone point me in the right direction of an example.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: If you want to save the files in the server you need to use a server side language.

Comment: What you want is rename local files using the web browser?

Comment: if you want to rename the file, you have to upload it on the server and save it there. The user's original copy will be unaffected by this action. Quite simply you can't make any changes to the local filesystem using Javascript - think of the security implications if a webpage could do that to your computer whenever it liked! Google has dozens of examples of how to upload files using HTML forms and PHP.

Comment: I'm sure that is what he means ADyson :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps are pretty simple. Assuming two fields `filename` and `photo`

Get them to submit the form via post, then:

```
$uploadDir = '/some/path/';
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'filename', FILTER_DEFAULT); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $uploadDir.$name)) {
   //success
} else {
    //fail
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not rename a file on the users local computer.  If they upload the file to your server, you can set the file name, but not on the local computer.

Comment: Hi all, Many thanks for your replies.